# Updating an object in a store in Svelte, is it by value or by reference?

Tags: svelte-store

Check out [this Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fc2be6aaa1dd42ad862ae4d73bebb66c?version=3.44.3). Notice how I access the global state – which is an object – by key and also iterate over its values in `App.svelte`. So I also create a derived list of these values in `global.js`.

- In general, is this the "Sveltonic" way (regarding performance, syntax, ...)?
- I am unsure what happens inside `.update()` (in `SetThings.svelte`). Will the full object or parts get copied into the old object? Or will the variable referencing the old object be reassigned to the new object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding part one of the question: It is unwise to use an outermost object. Instead, I now use a list and let the child objects have their indexes as keys. As shown in the Svelte docs, [for example here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks).

Regarding part two of the question, it seems the object (or parts of it) is not copied. See [update()](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/deed340cf5d9c278f9a0605297ad6e4a3a1579d9/src/runtime/store/index.ts#L87) → [set()](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/deed340cf5d9c278f9a0605297ad6e4a3a1579d9/src/runtime/store/index.ts#L68) → [safe_not_equal()](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/deed340cf5d9c278f9a0605297ad6e4a3a1579d9/src/runtime/internal/utils.ts#L39) (returns true in this case) → [value = value](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/deed340cf5d9c278f9a0605297ad6e4a3a1579d9/src/runtime/store/index.ts#L70)